# Role not created after using psql -c "create user...."

Tags: bash, postgresql, command-line, psql

I'm trying to create a script that creates readonly users but while trying to create a user my database doesn't update with the new user. The terminal returns a "CREATE ROLE" and no errors.

I've tried setting -U -h -p and calling the current_user() which shows that I'm the superuser making the call.

```
psql \
    -X \
    -U $PGUSERNAME 
    -h $DBHOST \
    -p $PORT \
    -c "create user readonly with password 'welcome';" \
    -d $DATABASENAME \
```

I'm connected to my postgres via goland and when I run the shell file which runs that psql the terminal returns a "CREATE ROLE" but the postgres isn't reflecting any new roles and when I run the query in the PostgresSQL console to find my readonly user 0 rows are found. I expected the shell script to create a user and update my local database.

Comment: Remove the final backslash, that looks suspicious. Maybe you are connecting to a different cluster. Have you tried using the `createdb` command that does the same thing, but is easier to use?

Comment: That worked, wow can't believe that "\" could be such evil. Thanks @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) mentioned in the comment removing the `\` at the end resolved this issue.